# JAX-RS 2 & OSGi in Glassfish 4 Not Working

Tags: jakarta-ee, osgi, glassfish-4.1

I'm trying to generate a sample application for the technologies I want to use in a project I'm working on.  Specifically, I want to create an OSGi Web Application Bundle (WAB) that implements JAX-RS 2 service endpoints.  I'm working through the RESTful Java with JAS-RS 2 book (by Bill Burke, I'd post a link, but I don't have enough reputation) for the conceptual JAX-RS service(s).  At this point I've implemented the customer services listed in chapter 3.  I've reviewed [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gkqff.html#gkunr) website several times, as well as several other resources on building WABs.  I'm using eclipse Luna with a dynamic web project, to which I have added the BND project nature.  I'm exporting the project as a .war in order to maintain the proper WAR structure.  I've manually verified that the OSGi manifest is in the correct place and contains the correct statements (i.e. matches what is in the IDE).

My problem is that when I deploy the file into Glassfish (I'm using Glassfish 4) as a WAR it deployss fine, and I can access the services.  However, because it isn't loaded as an OSGi bundle, I don't have access to other OSGi bundles.

When I deploy the file as an OSGi bundle (type: Other, OSGi checked), again it deploys fine, but doesn't seem to load into a Servlet Container, because all URLs return a 404 error.

Apparently I can only post 2 links, and code snippets count as links, so all I can include is my manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ShoppingApplication
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.restfully.shop
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.alpha
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes/
Bundle-Vendor: Perform Air International Inc.
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Web-ContextPath: /OrderEntry
Export-Package: com.restfully.shop.services;uses:="javax.ws.rs.core,javax.servlet,org.osgi.service.event,org.osgi.framework"
Import-Package: javax.servlet;version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)",javax.servlet.annotation,javax.servlet.http,javax.ws.rs.core,org.osgi.framework,org.osgi.service.event
Bundle-Activator: com.restfully.shop.osgi.WebAppContextListener
```

Let me know what other pieces of information might be useful, and I'll try to make them available to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You have org.osgi.service.event in your Import-Packages.

That doesn't exist in Glassfish 4.x from what I can tell. I get the following error when trying to deploy the camel-core-osgi bundle for example...

```
ERROR: org.osgi.service.event,version=[1.3,2) -- Cannot be resolved
```